# Add a column based on the JSON result set for JQUERY Datatables

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have a dataset (JSON) that has n columns for each row. Sometimes, few of these rows have n+1 data objects. How do i tell the datatable to show n+1 columns and display a either a null cell or the underlying data to this n+1th column? I deally i would like to display the n+1th column as a nested table, as it in itself is a arraylist. I have come across the drilldown columns in the jquery datatable, which i am currently exploring. Would need some pointers on how to display a '+' or '-' image to the n+1th column if the data exists/ not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
{   "mDataProp": null,
    "sClass": "control center",
    "bUseRendered" : false,
    "fnRender" : function(oObj) {
  if(oObj.aData["xyz"]){

      return '<img src="">';
  }else{
      return "NA";
  }

  }
}
```